# How to Configuring Graphqlrc.js Extension in VsCode for Shopify Functions Schema

Tags: graphql, configuration, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to configure the Graphqlrc.js for autocompletion using a Graphql schema.
I have installed "**GraphQL: Language Feature Support**" and my directory structure looks like this.

[image: Shopify Extention App Structure]

Here is the code for my .graphlrc.js file.

```
const fs = require("node:fs");

function getConfig() {
  const config = {
    projects: {},
  };

  let extensions = [];
  try {
    extensions = fs.readdirSync("./extensions");
  } catch {
    // ignore if no extensions
  }

  for (const entry of extensions) {
    const extensionPath = `./extensions/${entry}`;
    const schema = `${extensionPath}/schema.graphql`;
    if (!fs.existsSync(schema)) {
      continue;
    }
    config.projects[entry] = {
      schema,
      documents: [`${extensionPath}/**/*.graphql`],
    };
  }

  return config;
}

module.exports = getConfig();
```

I want the auto-completion feature to run in run.graphql and the schema can be found in the directory.